# Analyzing and Comparing Signals (Signal Processing) in Python: Fourier Transform?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I have thousands of signals. Every signal is recorded at the same frequency, but vary in the length of the signal.  It appears that there may be some pattern in the signal over time, perhaps periodicity.  What is the best way for me to process and look for a pattern in this signal, or to compare them (I can see that some signals are similar)?  Noise may be present.  I have been trying to figure out how to analyze it, maybe using Fourier Transform (in Python), but I am struggling (yet determined). Any tips, information references (books, videos), ANYTHING, is so greatly appreciated.  I am new to programming and signal processing; I am using Python.  If Fourier Transform (FT) is an option, if someone could give me a basic example of how to analyze (via FT) this type of data in Python, IT WOULD MAKE MY YEAR, and give me a starting point!! Thanks.
Example of two of the signals:

signal 1: [0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.36, 0.27, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, 0.27,0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.36…..]

signal2: [[0.18, 0.18, 0.09, 0.18, 0.09, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, 0.27, 0.36, 0.27, 0.36…….]
Example graph of my signal versus time:

Signal 1:
[image: Signal 1]

Signal 2:
[image: Signal 2]

Comment: This is more of a DSP theory question than an actual programming question at this point. I suggest you move it to http://dsp.stackexchange.com, where you are more likely to get a good response. Once you have a general approach and/or algorithm then the coding part should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: This data is extremely quantized (that is, the signal’s variability occupies a tiny portion of the sensor’s dynamic range—in your first signal, only five discrete values…) and that might lead to poor results after further processing. People sometimes dither (add a tiny bit of noise, to smooth out the jumps) their heavily-quantized data but that’s risky—if possible, I’d go back and re-collect the data so the signal’s peak-to-peak occupies more of the dynamic range of the sensor.

Comment: But if you think there’s some periodicity there that you can discern in this over-quantized data, look at the various spectral estimators in SciPy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#spectral-analysis E.g., the bottom of the `periodogram` documentation shows a real example. A spectral estimator is just some statistics magic on top of FFT. You can form spectrograms of the various signals and try to see if some signals exhibit the same periodicities.

Comment: If this sounds very hand-wavy, it is—looking for patterns in the data is very bad research. You should first form a hypothesis, then collect data to test only that hypothesis. A lot of problems today come from people data mining—i.e., testing all kinds of hypotheses with a single data set—and then finding some pattern in the noise.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This helps me put it in perspective.  I actually have a very specific hypothesis on this data, but wanted to see if I could just use "blind" math to see if it tells me anything.  There are discrete points in time where I expect the signal to change.  I will rethink this as DSP and repost as need be. Thank you for the perspectives and ideas: greatly valued!